# The WebDriver object is null in the @BeforeTest method in the test class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, factory, pageobjects

I'm using `Page Object Model` + `PageFactory` + `@Factory` + `@DataProvider`

I have 6 users to run and the thing is that I cannot login to 2 users in the same browser instance; each user can only login in a fresh browser instance.


So I create 6 suites, one for each user, and run all of them at once. (The driver object is created in `@BeforeSuite`)

Each suite contains multiple test tags and each test tag contains multiple class tags; the number of class tags is decided using `@Factory`

I'm creating my testng.xml programmatically.

It will look like this :

```
<suite name="user1">
  <test>
    <classes>
      <class name="SearchPerson" />
      .
      .
      .
      <class name="SearchPerson" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test>
    <classes>
      <class name="PrintPerson" />
      .
      .
      .
      <class name="PrintPerson" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>

and similarly 5 more suites for the other 5 users
```

Here's the project structure :

SearchPerson `extends` TestEngine `extends` TestBase

TestBase.java

```
public WebDriver webDriver;

public createChromeDriver(){
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path to chromedriver.exe);
  webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

TestEngine.java

```
public TestEngine extends TestBase{

  @BeforeSuite
  public void setUp(){
     createChromeDriver();
     webDriver.get("https://www.google.com");
  }

  @DataProvider
  public static Object[][] getTestData(){
     return Object[][]{ {"name1"}, {"name2"} };
  }

  @AfterSuite
  public void close(){
     webDriver.quit();
  }

}
```

My actual Test - SearchPerson.java

```
public class SearchPerson extends TestEngine{

  String name;
  Person person;

  @Factory(dataProvider = getTestData, dataProviderClass = TestEngine.class)
  public SearchPerson(String name){
      this.name = name;
  }

  @BeforeTest
  public void initPageObjects(){
     person = new Person(webDriver);
  }

   @Test
   public void setName(){
      person.setName(name);
   }

   @Test
   public void printName(){
      person.printName();
   }
}
```

I also do not want to make my WebDriver object static since I plan to parallelize my tests.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** 
**1. One can save attributes from within configuration methods which can later be accessed from any other annotated methods

2. Objects created in @BeforeSuite will ONLY be available to the first test in that suite**

After asking the same question on the TestNG Google Group, I found out objects created in @BeforeSuite will ONLY be available to the first test in that suite.

So I changed my XML in a way that the  tags represent the users, not the  tags.

My new XML looks like this :

```
<suite>
  <test name="user1">
    <classes>
      <class name="PrintPerson" />
      ..
      <class name="PrintPerson" />
      <class name="SearchPerson" />
      ..
      <class name="SearchPerson" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="user2">
    <classes>
      <class name="PrintPerson" />
      ..
      <class name="PrintPerson" />
      <class name="SearchPerson" />
      ..
      <class name="SearchPerson" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Another important thing I learnt was that one can save attributes from within configuration methods which can later be accessed from any other annotated methods.
In my case, since I now initialize my WebDriver object in @BeforeSuite, I save this object under the attribute 'webDriver'

```
@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite(ITestContext testContext){
   driver = new ChromeDriver();   
   testContext.setAttribute("webDriver", driver);
}
```

and accessing this in @BeforeTest in my test class

```
class Test1{
   WebDriver driver;
   
   @BeforeTest
   public void beforeTest(ITestContext testContext){
      driver = (WebDriver) testContext.getAttribute("webDriver");
   }

   @Test
   public void testMethod(){
      driver.get("https://www.google.com");
   }
}
```